Curry Predicate
Is there a workaround in typescript to have a predicate on a higher-order function?
type One = {
  _type: 'one';
  value: unknown;
};

type Two = {
  _type: 'two';
  value: unknown;
};

type Discriminated = One | Two;

const is =
  <O extends Discriminated>(obj: O) =>
  <K extends O['_type']>(key: K): obj is Extract<O, { _type: K }> =>
    obj._type === key;

// => Error: Cannot find parameter 'obj'.ts(1225)


One could combine the two parameters but that is exactly what I do not want.
EDIT:
This is a workaround as @Bergi mentioned:

const isReversed =
  <O extends Discriminated, K extends O['_type']>(key: K) =>
  (obj: O): obj is Extract<O, { _type: K }> =>
    obj._type === key;

Maybe someone can update this if in the future this might become possible.

Swap the parameter order? You cannot create a type predicate for a variable in an upper scope.

@Bergi Thanks for the reply. I updated the question.

You can flip isReversed, but that loses the type predicate, const is: (obj: Discriminated) => (key: "one" | "two") => boolean https://tsplay.dev/w8Dx4w

@Caleth Keeping the predicate is a requirement, but I am going to steal this idea for some functional programming tasks, thanks!
